# How do I provision push notifications for iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, push

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1

Apple's first instruction is "click app ids" but dont see it on the left side... so I think I may be looking in the wrong place/page.

So- does anyone have a clearer explanation on how to provision push notifications for iOS?

Comment: I'm looking for a real programming question but dont see it

Comment: How do I provision push notifications for iOS? Why isnt that a real question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think so you have admin rights for that account. You just have developer rights for that account.

Comment: Do you see iTune Connect option on “iOS Developer Program” on Apple developer home page ?

Comment: You are not admin. I am 100% confident. Ask someone who created that account.